# Can I legally publish a compilation of copyrighted material without licence? How?

Tags: united-states, copyright, european-union, fair-use, switzerland

I have bought a book A which contains much content, and a second book B which relies on some of that content. I took the time to compile *only* the content from A that is relevant for use with B into a new work for my own private use (PDF file).

Now I would like to make my derived work of A publically available, so that future users of B do not have to spend time again to perform the same work I already did. I assume, that I can not legally do this, but am asking here to be sure.

Assume I would be ready to publish my derivative work non-commercially and give up as many rights on it as neccessary to publish it. Is it then possible for me to legally publish my derivative work?
Maybe by claiming fair use?

Would it make it more legal in any way if I were to add a disclaimer "By clicking download, you verify that you already own A and B.". That is comparable to websites which require you to be 18+, for example.

I am interested in U.S., Swiss, and if available international EU-jurisdication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You may not do this. As your post points out this is a blatant copyright violation. It isn't remotely in the realm of fair use.

Comment: Thanks! Would it still be copyright violation If I would only distribute it to people who already own the books A and B? (Disregarding whether my idea of a disclaimer would be sufficient or however I would do that. Let's say I have some way to verify that.)

Comment: @lucidbrot Yes. It would still be a copyright violation.